# How to label the last three rows of a table as "a" using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, line, rows

How to label the last two rows of a table as "test" and the other rows as "-" using pandas in python?

Example:

```
+-------+
|sample |
+-------+
|    abc|
|    bcd|
|    cde|
|    edc|
+-------+
```

Become:

```
+-------++-------+
|sample ||result |
+-------++-------+
|    abc||      -|
|    bcd||      -|
|    cde||   test|
|    edc||   test|
+-------++-------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If there are 2 or more rows in DataFrame use:

```
df['result'] = ['-'] * (len(df.index) - 2) + ['test'] * 2

print (df)
  sample result
0    abc      -
1    bcd      -
2    cde   test
3    edc   test
```

If possible one row DataFrame:

```
df['result'] = ['-'] * (len(df.index) - 2) + ['test'] * min(len(df.index), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

N = 2
df['result'] = np.where(np.arange(len(df))<len(df)-N, '-', 'test')
```

output:

```
  sample result
0    abc      -
1    bcd      -
2    cde   test
3    edc   test
```